# ColumnDefinition in ListView DataTemplate does not expand to full width

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I'm creating a `ListView` with `DataTemplate` is a only text and a button. I want the button to be right most side and text is to left most side. However I noticed that it seems like my `Grid.ColumnDefinitions` not take all the space of the `ListViewItem` (Or I thought so). I want them to expand to full width.

```
<ListView Padding="5" x:Name="RecipeList" FontSize="15">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
               <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1">Delete</Button>
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default content alignment for a `ListViewItem` (the container of the content which is defined by your data template) is `Left`, so the `Grid` will only take as much space as it needs, but does not scale to the available width. Change it to `Stretch` is an item container style instead.

```
<ListView Padding="5" x:Name="RecipeList" FontSize="15">
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
               <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1">Delete</Button>
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Your columns are defined that the `TextBlock` and the `Button` take equal proportions in the grid. If you want to align the `Button` to the right and the `TextBlock` to take the remaining space, set the `Width` of the second column to `Auto`. Then the `Button` only uses as much space as it needs.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0"/>
   <Button Grid.Column="1">Delete</Button>
</Grid>
```